# Does the mass change for a body with eccentric orbit?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion

I am a student with a programming and electronics background attempting to recap on orbital mechanics. I would appreciate anyone with a physics specialisation helping me understand where my ignorance lies on the following:

According to Newtonian calculations the mass of a body orbiting another (larger body) can be calculated with:
$$ M = \frac{4\pi^2R^3}{GT^2} $$
The $T$ time period can be calculated by using the mean radius $R_m$:
$$ T= \sqrt{R_m^3} $$

My confusion arises when faced with the possibility of an orbit with high eccentricity value:

Using the above calculations only, a high eccentricity means a greater change in speed and thus radius, this then leads to the assumption that the specific mass at different orbital speeds will provide a slightly different mass, or rather will give me a changing "relativistic mass" $M_r$(?).

I'm assuming to then correct this to rest mass, I can use the rest Mass 
$$ M_0 = \frac{M_r}{\sqrt{(1-(v/c)^2}}$$

This leads to one of two issues with the equations I'm using.

1. Is the derivative of $M_0/M_r$ so small at most celestial objects speeds that using this correction is pointless?
2. Is my thinking/solution incorrect?

Comment: That equation comes is derived under the assumption that the orbit is circular.

Comment: Aha many thanks!, is there an alternative that factors in eccentricity?

Comment: Appreciate the edits for clarity!

Comment: I am not sure. I think a low eccentricity orbit would be well approximated by this equation, just using the average radius. This is *completely* unrelated to relativistic mass.

Comment: Isn't $M$ the mass of the *central* body, rather than the orbiting body as you claim?  (For the orbiting body, the mass appears both in the law of gravity and Newton's law and thus cancels out.)

Comment: Hmm,thanks for the suggestion, although the code library I'm building requires the same mass output for different points in both circular and elliptical orbits. (This is due to system based hardware restrictions from a server)
Good news that relativistic mass isn't a factor, will certainly save on RAM.

Comment: Norbert:
I'm not 100% sure, here's the source to that equation :http://image.gsfc.nasa.gov/poetry/ask/a10448.html (Dr. Sten Odenwald)

Comment: Its title says "How can I calculate the Earth's mass knowing only the distance to the Moon and the length of the lunar month?".  Here, the earth is the central body. (And you can also see that $m$ cancels out.)

Comment: I assumed this could apply both ways :s. Still , glad your question is answered.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but it means your question does not make sense. And no, it can NOT be applied both ways.

Comment: hmm, ok, well thanks for pointing that out. looks like I'll have to use the suggested Vis-viva equation.

Comment: I think the problem is my trying to find a one size fits all equation, not that's it's any more time consuming to program them, just awkward for the A.I method I'm using.

Comment: In the suggested vis-viva equation, the mass is *still* the mass of the central body. I guess the question is, what do you really want to do.

Comment: Basically I'm wanting to generate all possible orbit interaction factors of all bodies from a star that has all properties defined.

Comment: mm, I'll expand:
A star of known mass, diameter, classification is known.
The number of and mass per orbiting body is known.

A model for their expected orbits is made, this begins with a rough definition of their eccentricity, inclination, orbit radius and relative velocity etc.

After this , Stored values from this "draft" data is modified depending on the level of abstraction required.

E.g from viewing the entire solar system (will simply display original basic orbits), to viewing only a few bodies - shows increasingly more detailed deviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about relativistic corrections - they are insignificant for most planetary orbital motion at the level you try to model/understand it.

You want to look at the *vis viva* equation which is [well explained on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation):
$$v^2 = GM\left(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\right)$$

where:
$v$ is the relative speed of the two bodies
$r$ is the distance between the two bodies
$a$ is the semi-major axis (a > 0 for ellipses, a = ∞ or 1/a = 0 for parabolas, and a < 0 for hyperbolas)
$G$ is the gravitational constant
$M$ is the mass of the central body

It allows you to calculate the orbital period and velocity regardless of the eccentricity. Among other things, it shows that the period scales with the semi-major axis of the orbit ($T^2\propto a^3$ which is also Kepler's third law). For a circle, the semimajor axis is equal to the radius; for a more eccentric orbit, there is no "radius" - but there is still a major axis...

See if that gets you going. Ask questions in the comments if this is not sufficiently clear.

Comment: Many thanks!, This will hopefully be enough as I'm deriving everything from a pseudo random based variables of stars.
Will let you know, Apologies I can't up vote this due to me current rep.

One problem that's bugging my however:
I am required to do perform similar equations based on a singularities properties *sigh, would this proportionality still apply?

Comment: Woot!, Just tested on 250 Billion different star - sun ranges without error. Which is good enough I say :)
(Yes GPU calculation is that amazing :P)

Comment: Just an update:
I've reordered things to reference the constant area speed
For simulation at least, it helps avoid error.

Comment: Yes conservation of angular momentum is one constraint you can use on the orbit - which is what "constant area in constant time" really is...

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!
Please forgive my engineering simplification of terms XD

Comment: Just an update:
I had to do iterative update based on time and recalculating perihelion with a given variation, after that all good :)